# Cryptic Error message on Javascript module import

Tags: javascript

the app starting point is main.html

In main.html, I introduce index.js via a  tag.

In index.js, I import a Paddle class from paddle.js

all 3 files are in the same directory

If I copy the Paddle class (which draws on rectangle on the bottom of the canvas on main.html) from paddle.js and paste it into index.js ... it works fine.

However, importing the Paddle class from the paddle module, results in nothing in the screen and what to me is a cryptic syntax error in the Chrome Javascript console: **"import Paddle from "/paddle"; Uncaught syntax error, unexpected identifier"**

the code:

main.html -- at the bottom of the  tag

```
<script src="index.js"> </script>
```

index.js

```
import Paddle from "/paddle";

let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

...
```

paddle.js

```
export default class Paddle {...}
```

I'm using chrome 70, but it also fails on Firefox 63 (both of which reportedly support modules out of the box)

I'm looking all over google and matching up syntax with the docs but can't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: you might need to some kind of loader to handle this file

Comment: are you using webpack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this and tell me if it does not help

```
<script type="module" src="index.js"> </script>
```

Comment: Yes, it does help, in a sense. The error message goes away, but Chrome quietly refuses to draw the rectangle on the screen. Firefox, is helpful, it complains about a CORS issue but clearly tries to access the paddle module. So I'm thinking the browsers think the resources are from different domains (I'm not serving the files, but opening them up off the filesystem, so I can sort of see that). I don't want to disable security features, so I think I'm just going to install a server and serve off localhost.

Comment: That's clearly another problem, which you should address in another question (this is Stack Overflow's rule). If my answer solved your first problem, consider upvoting and selecting it as correct, then create a new question with a new problem and we'll try to figure it out there.

Comment: agreed, not going to go down the rabbit hole because I was just opening file off the file system cause lazy. Not interested in mucking around with browser settings to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

In order to import from within an embedded script you have to add attribute="module" to the  tag of the embedded script. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export).

> The static import statement is used to import bindings which are
>   exported by another module. Imported modules are in strict mode
>   whether you declare them as such or not. The import statement cannot
>   be used in embedded scripts unless such script has a type="module".
>
> There is also a function-like dynamic import(), which does not require
>   scripts of type="module".